# VueJS Passing data Through render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, render

I'm currently working with VueJS 2, I would like to pass some params from the HTML to the VueJS component. Let me show you.

My Html Div looks like this :

```
<div id="app" :id="1"></div>
```

And my javascript :

```
new Vue({
  store, // inject store to all children
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

My App Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ id }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
   id: Number
  }
}
</script>
```

I would like to get the id passed in the Html, in my App component.
How should I do ?

Comment: id is not a good name for a prop, as it's already an attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
<div id="app" data-initial-value="125"></div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App, {
    props:{
      id: document.querySelector("#app").dataset.initialValue
    }
  })
})
```

But you don't have to use a render function.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template:"<app :id='id'></app>",
  data:{
    id: document.querySelector("#app").dataset.initialValue
  },
  components:{
    App
  }
})
```

Also, I'm using `querySelector` assuming you rendered `initialValue` (instead of `id`) to the page as an attribute, but you could just as easily put it somewhere else on the page like a hidden input or something. Really doesn't matter.

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work as is, but it seemed to work if retrieved the value of the attribute on a line before new Vue(), stored it as a variable, and passed the variable in as the property value

Comment: @Zak, you're correct. the #app will be replaced with the vue instance once created.